# Не работает Install Package в Sublime Text3

Tags: sublime-text-3

Не работает Install Package в Sublime Text 3. В течении полугода плагины Sublime работали. Потом появились сообщения о том, что около 10 плагинов не работают. Решила удалить не рабочие и вновь установить. Но Install Package не подгружает новые плагины. Несколько раз повторно установила Sublime 3, старые и более новые версии. Ошибка та же, любые плагины не загружаются. Может, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Поделитесь, пожалуйста. Уже 3 день читаю по форумах - нигде не нашла ответ.
Код в консуле:

```
`DPI scale: 1
startup, version: 3143 windows x64 channel: stable
executable: /C/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe
working dir: /C/Sublime Text 3
packages path: /C/Users/MY/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /C/Users/MY/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Local
zip path: /C/Sublime Text 3/Packages
zip path: /C/Users/MY/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Vintage"]
pre session restore time: 0.35172
startup time: 0.42372
first paint time: 0.42472
reloading plugin Default.auto_indent_tag
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.convert_syntax
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.install_package_control
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.profile
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.run_syntax_tests
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.settings
reloading plugin Default.show_scope_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin Default.ui
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
reloading plugin Package Control.1_reloader
reloading plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
plugins loaded
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2018-01-25 
16:15:33, next run at 2018-01-25 17:15:33 or after
Package Control: Error parsing JSON from channel 
https://web.archive.org/web/20160103232808/
https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json.
Package Control: Error parsing JSON from channel 
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nick1m/660ed046a096dae0b0ab/
raw/e6e9e23a0bb48b44537f61025fbc359f8d586eb4/channel_v3.json.
ignored packages updated to: ["1337 Color Scheme", "Vintage"]
reloading settings Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
Package Control: Error parsing JSON from channel 
https://web.archive.org/web/20160103232808/
https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json.
Package Control: Error parsing JSON from channel 
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nick1m/660ed046a096dae0b0ab/
raw/e6e9e23a0bb48b44537f61025fbc359f8d586eb4/channel_v3.json.
error: Package Control

An error occurred while trying to unzip the package file for 1337 Color 
Scheme. Please try installing the package again.
ignored packages updated to: ["Vintage"]
reloading settings Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Судя из лога и url этот пакет уже не существует по этому url, удалите его и всё должно заработать.